# How to replace a column with strings into a column with integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-preprocessing

I Am trying to predict a dataset, which has a column with different strings. For example, there are 3 brands, 'A', 'B', and 'C', and i want to replace them with numbers (0, 1 and 2, for example).

I know how to do that if there were only 2 brands, using `pd.eq`,

I have tried to use `set`, but i'd like to know if there is an easier method to do that, since i will have to replace it with columns that have more than 5 differente strings, and it would be pretty annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace them by selecting the records that match those condition, assuming you have your data in `df` and the column of interest is `'Brand'`:

```
replacement = { 'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2 }
for key, value in replacement.items():
    df.loc[df['Brand'] == key, 'Brand'] = value
```

Comment: That will do, ty very much

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['Brand'].map({'A': 0, 'B':1,'C': 2})
```